# What's the meaning of 厨 in internet slang?

Tags: meaning, internet-slang

I was in a Chinese forum for manga fans and I saw a user who introduced himself saying this sentence:

> 一个普通的《X》厨

Going by the context, I understand 厨 here means something like "fan of X",  but I would like further information about the way Chinese people use this word and what it means to them. The dictionary only has "kitchen" and "cupboard" as meanings in English.

Comment: Note, the explanations given in this question ultimately originated from [this Japanese SE post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/239/use-of-%E5%8E%A8-on-the-internet).

Answer (score 4):

> [厨二病](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8E%A8%E4%BA%8C%E7%97%85)
>
> Japanese
>
> Etymology
>
> Derived by replacing the 中 (chū, “middle [school]”) with 厨 (chū, “freak; nerd”).
>
> 厨二病 (hiragana ちゅうにびょう, rōmaji chūnibyō)
>
> Alternative spelling of 中二病

This usage of **厨** here came from Japanese 'ちゅう' (kanji: 厨 ). Which means "**freak** or **nerd**"

"XX 厨" = "XX nerd"  or "XX freak". Anime and manga fans would be familiar with this term

*Other Japanese terms imported to Chinese via manga (mostly circulated among manga readers in written form)*

- *醬(ちゃん).*

*"XX 醬" = "XX 小妹妹" (Dear little XX)*

- *宅(taku)  came from Otaku (a young person who is obsessed with computers or particular aspects of popular culture to the detriment of their social skills..)*

*"XX 宅" = "XX obsessed" e.g. "軍事宅" means "a person obsessed with military"*

Answer (score 2):

In Japanese:

> 厨 (chu)

sounds the same as the first character of

> 中毒 (chudoku)

And `中毒` means sickly loves sb/sth. So "XX厨" basically means 'someone who sickly loves XX'. E.g. I'm a Gakki厨. I would do anything for her, including suicide.

Comment: Sounds like it'd be pretty similar to "Stan" in English-language internet slang. [From the Eminem song of the same name](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stan).

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about the details on how this word originated. Of course it is the a loanword from Japanese, and it is a substitution of 中, but I am not so sure which exact word that including 中. In [萌百](https://zh.moegirl.org/zh-hans/%E5%8E%A8) it says from the word 中坊(Japanese) that means middle school, which is the same as Tang's answer because the 中 in 中二 means middle school.

But the usage is very clear. X厨 means insane fan(s) of X. The focus is the "insane" part. In the beginning it is a negative word. Some one accuse others to be too crazy about an idol/work. But later on it is used by the fans themselves indicating that they enjoy the idol/work so much and would like to be crazy.

For now, it is tend to be a neutral word, and just means "fan" and less stress on the "insane" part, but be careful that this usage is only when speaking of oneself. If you say "I am a X厨." It can mean merely "I am a (normal) fan of X", or "I sickly love X." (as Kevin's answer said) But if you say "This guy is a X厨." it is somewhat offensive.

Answer (score -2):

> 一个普通的《X》厨

I might be wrong. My first impression is that it can be analogous to 她还是个"厨", meaning she is still virgin. So, I might think 一个普通的《X》厨 means he/she doesn't have much experience or knowledge about 《X》( not as much knowledge/experience as a normal fun has).

Comment: Virgin is 处女/处男, not 厨女/厨男

Comment: @LionelRowe I might be plain wrong about it.

Comment: @LionelRowe However, if it's not in written, I might interpret it like that. I'm not quite familiar with the context.